# Javascript anonymous decorators

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for a decorator to keep the wrapped function reference?

I'm not really sure how to explain the question other than the following code :

It's a minimal example, it doesn't make sense but in the context it does

```
const myObject = {
  myFunction : function(txt) {
    this.myOtherFunction(txt)
  },
  
  myOtherFunction : function(txt) {
    console.log(txt)
  }
}

function decorator(wrapped) {
  return function() {
    return wrapped.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

//Works
myObject.myFunction('Hello')
//But decorated it doesn't work
decorator(myObject.myFunction)('Hello')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returned by `decorator` expects that it is called with a specific `this` object, with which it calls the `wrapper` function. Since the correct functioning of your wrapper (`myObject.myFunction`) depends on passing the right `this` object, you must be sure to call `decorator` with that `this` binding.

So this will work:

```
decorator(myObject.myFunction).call(myObject, 'Hello')
```

Alternatively, you can pass a function to the decorator that has the correct `this` bound to it:

```
decorator(myObject.myFunction.bind(myObject))('Hello')
```

### Alternative: Without `this` dependency

Things would be less verbose if you would make your object methods independent of the value of `this`. There are several ways to do this, but here is one:

```js
const myObject = (function () {
   function myFunction(txt) {
       myOtherFunction(txt);
   }
   function myOtherFunction(txt) {
       console.log(txt);
   }
   return { myFunction, myOtherFunction };
})(); // IIFE

function decorator(wrapped) {
  return function() {
    return wrapped.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

//Works
myObject.myFunction('Hello')
//Also works
decorator(myObject.myFunction)('Hello')
```

### Alternative: A specific decorator function for *methods*

You could create a separate decorator function that needs two arguments: an object, and the name of the method (a string):

```js
const myObject = {
  myFunction : function(txt) {
    this.myOtherFunction(txt)
  },
  
  myOtherFunction : function(txt) {
    console.log(txt)
  }
}

function methodDecorator(obj, methodName) {
  return function() {
    return obj[methodName].apply(obj, arguments)
  }
}

//Works
myObject.myFunction('Hello')
//Also works
methodDecorator(myObject, "myFunction")('Hello')
```

Comment: Damn that is very verbose, isn't there an easier way?

Comment: See addition to answer. This is a broad subject. There are so many different ways to deal with `this`...

Comment: ...and added yet another alternative.